# Synchronize access to Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my app, I have a `SyncAdapter` which uses a `ContentProvider` to put data into the SQLiteDatabase. Everything was working perfectly for months. After I have added a second way to update the ContentProvider from GCM push notifications, I start getting crash reports from some users like

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850)
```

OR

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)
```

and several other exceptions related to sqlite.

Although I've heard that Sqlite is synchronized and we don't have to worry, I do get these errors that point that I need to synchronize somehow. Has anyone dealt with this issue?

EDIT:
Here's a sample stacktrace

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)
1   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
2   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:906)
3   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
4   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
5   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
6   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
7   
at com.makanstudios.conscious.provider.ConsciousProvider.doInsert(ConsciousProvider.java:225)
8   
at com.kaciula.utils.provider.BasicContentProvider.insert(BasicContentProvider.java:80)
9   
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
10  
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:866)
11  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.net.DatabaseHandler.updateStatsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:351)
12  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.net.DatabaseHandler.updateStatsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:362)
13  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.gcm.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:124)
14  
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
15  
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
16  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
17  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
18  
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

And another sample stacktrace:

```
0   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
1   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
2   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:318)
3   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:229)
4   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
5   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.reconfigure(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:339)
6   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.reopenReadWrite(SQLiteDatabase.java:832)
7   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:213)
8   
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
9   
at com.kaciula.utils.provider.BasicContentProvider.insert(BasicContentProvider.java:76)
10  
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:201)
11  
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:869)
12  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.net.DatabaseHandler.updateStatsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:351)
13  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.net.DatabaseHandler.updateStatsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:362)
14  
at com.makanstudios.conscious.gcm.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:124)
15  
at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
16  
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
17  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
18  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
19  
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: If you are using the same `SQLiteDatabase` object/instance, all access is synchronized. Hence, if you are using the same `SQLiteOpenHelper` object/instance, all access is synchronized. Contention issues would come from using more than one instance, or *maybe* more than one process.

Comment: I do use only one instance. In onCreate() in my ContentProvider I create the SQLiteOpenHelper instance and I use that in all my provider's methods to get the database. Maybe the problem is that in some methods I use getWritableDatabase() and in some getReadableDatabase() and somehow there is a race condtion.

Comment: Don't think you have a concurrency issue. In the case of the second error it's more likely that the device is running out of disk space (for 778).

Not sure about the first error, though. Do you have a stack trace? Which method causes it? An `INSERT` statement, a call to `getWritableDatabase()`, something else?

Comment: I've added one type of stacktrace. It always happens inside my GCMIntentService when I receive a push notification and want to insert something inside the db. The stacktraces are of several types.

Comment: Did you ever get around to fixing this issue? I am having similar problems.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe Nope. It still happens. I just catch the exceptions. I really can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm thinking `disk I/O error` means that maybe some of your users have bad flash drives?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single Helper inside your content provider code. So always connect 1 helper to 1 database and you won't have any issues.

As an alternative if you don't provide access to other applications there is no need to use a content provider.

I have been using content providers for a long time before I decided to switch to ORMLite. And it has been working great so far in all my projects. Maybe check that out.

Comment: I am using only one helper in my content provider. And I like working with the Content provider because I get a lot of benefits from using it and the Android guys recommend it and all google apps use it.

Comment: Yes that fine by my standards :)

Comment: Have you checked out the Notepad tutorial. I have been using the code in that manner and i have never had concurrency issues.

Comment: Lately no. But my content provider code is based on the Google I/O app from last year. Maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere. Need to look more into it. Thanks.

Comment: DArkO,kaciula,Chris Martin  can you please help me regarding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714771/android-camera-take-picture-failed-issue