# Which conditions cause SQLiteDiskIOException code 3850

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-contentprovider

I have an app that uses ContentProvider to access SQLite. An instance of SQLiteOpenHelper is created in providers onCreate:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    final Context context = getContext();
    mDBHelper = new MyDatabase(context);        
    return true;
}
```

SQLiteDatabase instances retrieved in methods insert/update/delete/query are not manually closed. None of these methods are marked synchronized. ContentProvider is accessed from multiple threads started from UI and services.

Sample stacktrace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1574)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
at com.sample.provider.MyProvider.update(SourceFile:0)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:260)
at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1040)
```

Things worked fine up to the moment when I added a class that serializes writes to certain tables using a Handler initialized by Looper from HandlerThread. After this I started seeing plenty of SQLiteDiskIOExceptions with error codes 3850 and 0 (not an error?). Interestingly 90% of these crashes occur with Nexus 4 and on a handful of other devices.

I have been running Unit tests trying to simulate the condition but have been unable to reproduce the problem. There are other questions that already discuss related issues (e.g. here: [Synchronize access to Content Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610709/syncronize-access-to-content-provider)) but to me the original cause for this error seems still a bit unclear. So what really are the reasons for error 3850?

Comment: It's *SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK* and according to [SQLite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) "Usually an SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK error indicates a problem obtaining a PENDING lock." So it's related to concurrency in a database since an update operation couldn't be executed due to another unreleased lock.